# Unity AR Foundation object anchor problem

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit

I am new on unity ar foundation and I am trying to create simple screen that when camera looks to the target image, my object will be visible at that point and some other objects will be visible according to first object position (referans point).

When camera looks the target image, my object becomes visible but when I move camera, object also moves with camera direction as well like that; [check here to see video](https://streamable.com/scg46)

What can I do to keep object always at the same point even camera moves (even it can be render once -no update-).. any advise ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Which AR platform do you working on? (ARKit & ARCore) You don't need an anchor if you use the tracked image. Because it is already an anchor. Update your game object transform if only if tracked image anchor tracking state is tracking & limited. Also the image you provided has few trackable features. You should test your code with an image that has more features than the current image.  Also setting the image's physical size correctly greatly improves tracking.